# Is it possible to prevent running of 2 instance of a java application in a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

As task scheduler doesn't seem to be stopping me from running 2 instances, I have already enabled do not start a new instances

Comment: have searched and have no idea how to implement it, is there any way I can prevent another of my java application instance from running when i execute it in a batch file?

Comment: @nlsbshtr I don't think that's what the OP is looking for... He's asking if a batch file has the capability to not run an application if it is already running.  Not a java coding question.

Comment: if you want to do the locking in the batch file, on which OS is it running?

Comment: Not a batch file solution, but Launch4J (an EXE wrapper for Java) has this functionality.

Comment: @nlsbshtr Seems like overkill -- the application could just check process statuses to see if other applications of the same assembly are running and exit if so.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are actually asking for a batch solution rather than a Java one, and provided that you are starting the Java programs from the batch then you could do something like this

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq java.exe" | find /i "java.exe" >nul && (
echo Java already running, not going to run again
) || (
echo Java not running, so run it
java.exe whatever
)
```

Obviously you will have to replace `java.exe whatever` with your actual command.

If this isn't what you are looking for please add more specific info/requirements.

Comment: This is risky, because it could prevent your app from running if there is any other Java processes on the system running, not just *your* Java process.

Comment: @nlsbshtr I'm not sure about that, I don't know enough about Java's processes tbh, I just thought I would see if this would fit the OP's requirements.

Comment: @JohnnyO Yeah I see what you mean, I guess you could do it by ID's, but that would be messy with batch. I will see what the OP thinks first, if they can ideally give some more details.